# fetching input field values from a form using each

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a layout with multiple forms. what i want is to use a .each method to fetch those forms one by one, loop though its input values using class selector and get those values constructed in a JSON object. Need help with getting the values

```
this.$('form').each(function(index){
console.log($(this).children('.itemName').val());
```

This is being done in a backbone view. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to search for your input elements within a given element.

As your backbone view probably uses `this.el` your code might look like this:

```
$('form :input',this.el).each(function(index){
  if($(this).hasClass('itemName')) {
    console.log($(this).val());
  }
}
```

You could also filter your results like this:

```
var $inputs = $('form :input',this.el);
$inputs.filter(".item_name").each(function(){
  console.log("item name value:", $(this).val());
});
$inputs.filter(".itemQty").each(function(){
  console.log("itemQty element value:", $(this).val());
});
```

If you have only one element you could also skip `$.each`:

```
var $form= $('form',this.el);
console.log($(".itemName", $form).val());
console.log($(".itemQty ", $form).val());
```

Comment: No you are interpreting it wrong. i want to loop through all the input elements in 'this' form. there is one $(.itemName') another is .itemQty and so on...

Comment: anything more cleaner and simpler than this? may be using children or something? because of i have lot of inputs and checking "if"  for each of them is.....

Comment: @beNerd do you look for `filter`?

Comment: one thing to ask you. do i need to filter? actually there is one input with only one class. i mean i don't have itemName multiple times. just that i have multiple inputs with different classes. and i need to access each of them sepearately and form a json with proper index. hope you got what i want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24425/discussion-between-benerd-and-ghommey)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to serialize a form as JSON is to use [`jQuery's serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

```
JSON.stringify($('form').serializeArray());
```

Comment: No you are interpreting it wrong. i want to loop through all the input elements in 'this' form. there is one $(.itemName') another is .itemQty and so on...

Comment: this will serialize to `JSON` with all form elements by default, which meets your requirement, why do you need to manually get values by accessing class?

Answer (score 0):

You can get by this jQuery:

```
 $('form input').each(function(){ 
        alert($(this).val()); 
    });
```

Comment: No you are interpreting it wrong. i want to loop through all the input elements in 'this' form. there is one $(.itemName') another is .itemQty and so on...

Comment: $('form input').each(fuction(){
   alert($(this).val());
});  Try this

Comment: This wont match `select` or `textarea` elements.